# XSL for-each filtering; how to evaluate TWO variable in select?

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2007

```
<xsl:variable name="filterValue"
 >@subject = 'Subject To Filter On'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="$Rows[$filterValue]">
```

It seems to me that the $filterValue is being treated as a literal string rather than being evaluated. How can I make it so that the variable's value is evaluated instead?

*Desired result*:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Rows[@subject = 'Subject To Filter On']">
```

I apologize if this has been answered before, I don't know much terminology about XSL so I'm having trouble searching online. Thanks.

Comment: Dynamic XPath evaluation is not part of XPath 1.0/2.0 standard nor XSLT 1.0/2.0. There are extensions functions for XSLT processors implementing EXSLT or its own version. It might be possible that XSLT 3.0 includes such function. The main reason for this is that you would need a runtime enviroment, wich it wasn't part of XSLT processing model. If you extend your question with the specific constraint on the filter, then we could help you.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and a complete and easy solution. :)

Comment: Here is a reference to the EXSL extension function in order to complement Alejandro's answer: http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dynamic evaluation of XPath expressions is not supported in both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0.**

**Usually, there are workarounds.**

In this specific case you can have (global/external) parameters:

```
  <xsl:param name="attrName" select="'subject'"/>
  <xsl:param name="attrValue" select="'Subject To Filter On'"/>
```

**and then in your code:**

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Rows[@*[name()=$attrName] = $attrValue]">
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. That is hugely helpful. I'm faced with an additional constraint where I could have more than one filter and up to a maximum of 3 filters. Does that force me to have 6 params; 2 for each filter (as shown above)?